# Toggling position fixed and static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I have 2 columns. The right column is a normal scrollable pane of content. The left hand column, with classname `sticky` is the column I'm trying to toggle between fixed and static positioning. It must remain fixed in view as you scroll through the right hand column until the end. When you get to the end of the right hand column (and the next section becomes visible) the `sticky` div's position must change to static and scroll normally with the page. The following section must scroll in the same manner (normally) until it reaches the top of the browser window where the current `sticky` div in view changes to position fixed.

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div class="c-2 sticky"></div> /* Background image */
    <div class="c-2">
        <p>Any volume of content. Must cater for long and short pieces</p>
        ....
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 130px;
    position: relative;
}

.c-2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #e4f;
}

    .c-2.sticky {
        background: url(img/holder.jpg) fixed top center no-repeat #fff;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
           -moz-background-size: cover;
             -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover; 
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        width: 60%;
    }
```

The JS is where I fall down, I just don't know how to begin to do this. I've tried using [StickyKit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) but without any luck. I have a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6HPX5/

Comment: Generalizations like this question are frowned upon on stackoverflow. However, I did provide some ideas to get you started or at least looking into how to get it going...\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello please view this demo and tell me if something like this is what you want **http://jsfiddle.net/6HPX5/130/** then i can make a better explanation about this`.`

Comment: Yeah this is brilliant and just what I was looking for. I can't seem to integrate it in to my site though so an explanation would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: More info re above: The left hand column just won't stick and the page scrolls normally. Dev tools doesn't bring up any errors and nor does it show the abs or fix classes being added/removed. See working code: http://176.32.230.2/baodev.com/cjo/ Any ideas?

Comment: Try to add a console.log('msj') in the function or trace any var into the window.scroll function with this we can now where the problem is

Comment: I've put the console.log() code in my function but still no results in dev tools. Not sure I've implemented it correctly though, this is what I've done: http://pastebin.com/NM223C0q

Comment: Try to put the function outside everything in the js outside the document.ready

Comment: Still nothing in the console. I've even removed all other scripts to see if that interfered but no luck...

Comment: :/ the only way i see ---> Make a fiddle

Comment: The problem I had in my code was that the window wasn't the scrollable area so all I did was change this: $(window).scroll(function() { to this: $('#scroller').scroll(function() {

Comment: Is it possible to get this to work within a parent div and not body? I'm running into issues with the .fix class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put an "anchor" in where the new section begins and then with jQuery, you'll want to see the position of this element, and then once you determine that the anchor is visible use jQuery(id).css() option to change the position.

OR another alternative would be to track scrolling, and when the element on the left needs to move, use animate to move it off the screen.

**UPDATE**

http://api.jquery.com/css/ - to change the position attribute.

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ - to detect scrolling

http://api.jquery.com/position/ or http://api.jquery.com/offset/ - to get the position of your anchor.

And then you add this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(e) {
   //track scrolling
});
```

Comment: I understand your point but would you be able to provide any links to resources that you refer to?

Comment: I updated the response. You can use those tools to do what you want.